# Running a process with the TTY detached

Tags: linux, shell, tty

I'd like to run a linux console command from a terminal, preventing it from accessing the TTY by itself (which will, for example, happen often when the console command tries to request a password from the user - this should just fail). The closest I get to a solution is using this wrapper:

```
temp=`mktemp -d`
echo "$@" > $temp/run.sh
mkfifo $temp/out $temp/err
setsid sh -c "sh $temp/run.sh > $temp/out 2> $temp/err" &
cat $temp/err 1>&2 &
cat $temp/out
rm -f $temp/out $temp/err $temp/run.sh
rmdir $temp
```

This runs the command as expected without TTY access, but passing the stdout/stderr output through the FIFO pipes does not work for some reason. I end up with no output at all even though the process wrote to stdout or stderr.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why not do `my_script </dev/null >/dev/null`?

Comment: @Roadowl The redirects don't help if my_script opens `/dev/tty` explicitly. Try `head -n1 /dev/tty < /dev/null > /dev/null`. It blocks for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, thank you all for having a look. Turns out that the script already contained a working approach. It just contained a typo which caused it to fail. I corrected it in the question so it may serve for future reference.